# Steps for change the UI of desktop app from winforms to wpf

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-interface

I built a small desktop app on c# .net
Local desktop without any internet connection or communication with other any computers, I used winforms.

As expected I split up between logic and UI, and now I want to use WPF to my UI (change the way I implement the UI part), and in the future I will want to use mobile UI..
What are my steps should be?
Do I need to write new code, or there is something automatic?

Comment: you need to do that manually.

Comment: yes you need to write new code. WinForms and WPF are totally different

Comment: In case I want to run my app on Android/iOS ,do I need to write new logic code or the current logic code could move as is?

Comment: Wpf is windows only. Decide what you need to target before you start writing code. Maybe this should be a web page or xamarin forms or react native.